# MySQL Bottleneck

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ID, SourceID, EventId, Starttime, Stoptime
```

All of the ID columns are char(36) and the times are dates.

The problem is that querying the table is really slow. I have 7 millons rows, I have about 60-70 threads that are writing (insert or update) to the table all the time.

On the other side I have the GUI that needs to read from this table, and it's here it get slow. If I want to select all the events that have been made `where SourceID = something` it takes almost 300 seconds. SourceID has an index. I take the same query and put explain keyword first I got this.

```
select type = simple
type = ref
possible_keys = sourceidnevent,sourceid
key = soruceid
key_len = 109
ref = const
rows = 84148
```

And the query

```
SELECT * FROM tabel where sourceid='28B791C7-D519-4F0C-BC03-EFB1D4AC9CEB'
```

However I started to think about what does I really need from the table. I want to know which event occured on which server, and also which event occured on servers, sorted by date. I have added index for all combination of which *where* and *order by* are used.

I need all the rows for becuse I want to make some calculation on them, some grouping, avarage and so on. But I'm doing it in .NET enviroment insteed of asking many question.

However if I add a limit to the select it goes faster. So is the bottleneck the amount of data that is transfered and not actully the *finding/selecting part*? If so I can rebuild my application to do the calculation on only one day and save the result into another table, and later aggregate all of it.

How can I speed up the procecss? Would it be better to switch to MongoDB? I currently use MySQL and InnoDB.

Comment: It can be cached for 15 min. But I want to point out that the UI most reponse quick, even if it access the data the first time, so I don't know how to cache it unless preloading everything in the UI layer.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what indexes are available, what queries are being returned, how the DBMS has been tuned, what operating system it runs on, what filesystem it sits on, how the OS has been tuned, why the 'id' fields are varchar, there's only limited information about access contention.

Comment: I updated the quesiton:
If I add a limit to the select it goes faster. So is the bottleneck the amount of data that is transfered? If so I can rebuild my application to do the calculation on only one day and save the result into another table, and later aggregate all of it.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to replace GUID with bigint and retest the query? 2. Is it and option to memorize the result of call (query exec + calculation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of information you've not provided here - some of which I've mentioned in my comment elsewhere.

NoSQL is unlikely to be much faster than MySQL on a single node. I'd be very surprised if it were faster than using the [handler API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/handler.html) on MySQL along with appropirate indexes.

You've provided part of an explain plan (but not the query being explained) - but you haven't provided any interpretation of this:

> rows = 84148

Does it really need to process that many rows to provide the result you need? If so and the result is not aggregated then maybe you need to think about why you need to ship 80k rows of data to the front end. If it's only having to return a few non-aggregated rows then you really need to analyse your indexes.

> I have added index for all combination

Too many indexes is just as bad for performance as too few.